# Remove shopping aspect from question?

Tags: discussion, good-questions

The question [Is Klook reliable for buying e-tickers for Singapore's tourist attractions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105069/is-klook-reliable-for-buying-e-tickers-for-singapores-tourist-attractions) ends with the additional question

> Is there any other website like Klook where I can book e-tickets at discounted price?

We [discourage shopping questions on SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad). The question currently has [one answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/105074/40521) that only answers that last question. It attracted my attention in the first post review queue because it smelled spammy.

IMO we should edit out that final question and stick to the core about the reliability of Klook.
But maybe some degree of 'list questions' are OK for this SE site?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Done. I have removed the list-type question asking for other discounted sites.